# Draw a circle on the MapControl

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am aware of technique to draw a circle by generating points by basic math and then use the points to create a MapPolygon.

Is there another way?

For example, I see there is a class for circles:

```
public sealed class Geocircle : IGeocircle, IGeoshape
```

But I don't know how to use it, there doesn't seem to be any `MapLayer` for it.

Answer (score 1):

`Geocircle` is used to create a geographic circle object for the given position and radius. It often use to make map [`Geofence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/set-up-a-geofence), but not to display the cycle on the map.

There many way that draw a circle on the map

**[generating points](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MapLocation/blob/master/CheckPointApplication/MainPage.xaml.cs#L311) by basic math**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 360; i++)
{
//draw a cycle
BasicGeoposition point = new BasicGeoposition() 
{ Latitude = centerLatitude + ri * Math.Cos(3.6 * i * 3.14 / 180), Longitude = centerLongitude + ri * Math.Sin(3.6 * i * 3.14 / 180) };
list.Add(point);
}
```

**Add [Ellipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/shapes#ellipse) to [map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#add-xaml)**

```
private void MyMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify a known location.
    BasicGeoposition snPosition = new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 47.620, Longitude = -122.349 };
    Geopoint snPoint = new Geopoint(snPosition);

    // Create a XAML border.
    var ellipse1 = new Ellipse();
    ellipse1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Coral);
    ellipse1.Width = 200;
    ellipse1.Height = 200;

    // Center the map over the POI.
    MyMap.Center = snPoint;
    MyMap.ZoomLevel = 14;

    // Add XAML to the map.
    MyMap.Children.Add(ellipse1);
    MapControl.SetLocation(ellipse1, snPoint);
    MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(ellipse1, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am already aware of doing it like you showed. It's pretty bad there's no way to add a circle by an MapElement

Answer (score 0):

You can create XAML shapes and add them as a child to the `MapControl`. Then you set their location using `SetLocation`:

```
var circle = new Ellipse() { 
   Height = 20, 
   Width = 20, 
   Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
};
map.Children.Add(circle);
var location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
{
   Latitude = 51.1789,
   Longitude = -1.8261
});
map.SetLocation(circle, location);
```

The `Geocircle` class is used for [geofencing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/set-up-a-geofence), so it is not applicable here.